# How to send dynamic Label to another column of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

How to send dynamic label value into another column of TableLayoutPanel in window forms. I am having two columns one at left side and next one at right side of the TableLayoutPanel. Here is my code:

```
lblOpt4.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblOpt4);
```

by using Dock text is displaying at right side but in left column of TableLayout panel entire text flow is missing (sequence of text is missing)

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblOpt4);  // adds to the TFP
lblOpt4.AutoSize = false;                 // allows for multiple lines, if needed
lblOpt4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;            // fills the Cell, if needed
tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumn(lblOpt4, 1);  // sets the column
```

To fine tune you may want to play with `Padding` and/or `Margin`..

If needed you would set the row with :

```
tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(lblOpt4, row);   // sets the row
```